# What is the reasons to use asynchronous I/O on socket?

Tags: sockets

From the manpage, `select()` is synchronous I/O multiplexing which means that only when some file descriptors are ready to read or write, the procedure keeps going next for further operations. This means that `read()`ing  data from that fd will not be blocked, and the total bytes read will be returned. However, we can also set an `O_NONBLOCK` flag with `fcntl()` function for non-blocking I/O. What is the main difference between using `select()` and `O_NONBLOCK`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select` allows you to monitor multiple descriptors with a timeout for different events.

`O_NONBLOCK` is used in a situation when the current thread should not wait for I/O to complete. This is desirable when you are doing more things in the same thread, like updating the UI. In that case, you don't want the thread to pause waiting for the I/O to complete.